# How does append() work behind the scenes that's causing this?

Tags: arrays, go, data-structures, slice

I'm pretty new to Go and trying to track down a bug in my codebase. In the process I've distilled the problem down to a single call to `append()`, but can't figure out why it's behaving the way it is...

```
func main() {
    foo := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    fmt.Printf("before: %v\n", foo)

    i := 0
    noop(append(foo[:i], foo[i+1:]...)) // -- call append, but do nothing with the result
    fmt.Printf(" after: %v\n", foo)
}

func noop(a interface{}) {} // -- avoid "evaluated but not used" errors
```

[Try it here](https://play.golang.org/p/a7enw6eWJm)

So, what the heck is really going on here?

Comment: You mutate the `foo` by appending to a `foo[:i]` slice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`append(foo[:i], foo[i+1:]...)` does the following:

1. It takes the `foo[:i]` slice, which is `foo[:0]` and basically a slice with length `0` and capacity (at least) `3`.
2. As soon as the capacity is enough to append the values - the underlying array is reused
3. You write `b` and `c` into the indexes `0` and `1` correspondingly of the underlying array.

Then you check the `foo` variable that uses the underlying array we just modified and that contains the `b c c` values.

Compare with the following:

```
noop(append(foo[:i], "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"))
```

Here the list of values to append is longer than the current capacity. So the runtime allocates a new underlying array. And you don't mutate the `foo`. https://play.golang.org/p/RooYG_p9Z8

Comment: Wow. I assume reusing the original array is for performance reasons, but this is a very unintuitive side effect! So if you were looping through an array and removing elements, how would you do it if you needed to remove the first element (i = 0)? I guess you'd have to detect `i == 0` and have a special case like `foo = append([]T{}, foo[1:])`?

Comment: @KOGI create a new slice instead then and append to it. Or simply `foo[1:]` is a slice "without" the first value. "but this is a very unintuitive side effect! " --- it's not intuitive to not use the returned result either.

Comment: so I'd still need a special case for `i == 0`? Is there no way to do this that works the same for `i = 0` _and_ `i > 0`?

Comment: @KOGI it works the same for every index. `foo = append(...)` and there won't be surprises

Comment: that's great if I want to modify the original, but what if I wanted `bar := append(foo[:i], foo[i+1:])` _without_ the side-effect of also modifying `foo`?

Comment: `bar := append([]string{}, foo[:i]...); bar = append(bar, foo[i+1:]...)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146216/discussion-between-kogi-and-zerkms).

Comment: This is why the recommend usage of `append` is *always* `myvar = append(myvar, thing)` - you always assign the result of append back to the variable containing the slice you're appending to. Anything else can result in unexpected/hard to predict behavior.

Answer (score 3):

> If the capacity of `s` is not large enough to fit the additional values, `append` allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise, `append` re-uses the underlying array.

Breaking it down, `s` here is `foo[:0]`, which has a capacity of at least 3, since the length of `foo` is 3. `s` has 0 elements, and append wants to add two elements, `[b c]`, so there is room, and `append` will re-use the underlying array of `foo[:0]` which is the same as the underlying array of `foo`.

So it places the items `[b c]` at the beginning of the array, and returns a new slice of that array with a length of 2.

But you're still looking at `foo`, which is a slice of that same array, but still has a length of 3; the third item is the `c` which hasn't been touched, so `foo` is now `[b c c]`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also relatively new to go, but the way I understand `append` is that it appends all the following arguments to the first argument.

So essentially what you are doing is appending `foo[1]` and `foo[2]` to `foo[0]` and `foo[1]` without actually changing the length of `foo`.

If you want to preserve the original slice what you want is [this](https://play.golang.org/p/1R5u_1-nAt)

Comment: This is not accurate. How could you "append ... to foo ... without actually changing the length of foo"? Appending to something increases its length, by definition.